# VB.NET how to get session id out of JSON string

Tags: vb.net, split, sessionid

i'm trying to get the session id out of a string looking like this:

> `{"url":"","port":1337,"status":"OK kPzKTe0SNYGRWsPxoiK8jg5qllvPLn7hG4MRFSjqU60w4525175","session":"kPzKTe0SNYGRWsPxoiK8jg5qllvPLn7hG4MRFSjqU60w4525175","username":"foobar","secret":"1c25687b71f183e53009dd0156becfe5","user_id":1337,"vip":0}`

it's the id after *"session":* **kPzKTe0SNYGRWsPxoiK8jg5qllvPLn7hG4MRFSjqU60w4525175**

i tried alot with split and stuff but couldnt get it done so far. any ideas? btw: the output isnt always same order. url status session change positions each time i request it.

```
Function MySplitFunction()
    FrmConsole.Console.Text = FrmConsole.Console.Text & "[API] getting sid" & vbCrLf


    Dim client As New WebClient
    Dim sessionid As String = client.DownloadString("https://www.spin.de/api/login?login=usr;pw=pass;server=1337")
    Dim Splitted() As String = sessionid.Split(New String() {"""session""", ","}, StringSplitOptions.None)


    FrmConsole.Console.Text = FrmConsole.Console.Text & "SID: " & Splitted(1) & vbCrLf

End Function
```

Comment: That string appears to be JSON data so you should look into how to read JSON in VB. Once you know the basics of that you can give it a go and, if you have an issue, ask a more specific question.

Comment: wow that looks promising ill try that thanks mate. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your JSON text to the clipboard then use `Edit>Paste Special>Paste JSON as Classes` to create your class. Then use `System.Text.Json` to deserialize:

```
Imports System.Text.Json

Module Program
  Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim myJsonString = "{""url"":"""",""port"":1337,""status"":""OK kPzKTe0SNYGRWsPxoiK8jg5qllvPLn7hG4MRFSjqU60w4525175"",""session"":""kPzKTe0SNYGRWsPxoiK8jg5qllvPLn7hG4MRFSjqU60w4525175"",""username"":""foobar"",""secret"":""1c25687b71f183e53009dd0156becfe5"",""user_id"":1337,""vip"":0}"
    Dim myJsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of MyJsonClass)(myJsonString)
    Console.WriteLine(myJsonObject.session)
    Console.WriteLine("Finished.")
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub
End Module

Public Class MyJsonClass
  Public Property url As String
  Public Property port As Integer
  Public Property status As String
  Public Property session As String
  Public Property username As String
  Public Property secret As String
  Public Property user_id As Integer
  Public Property vip As Integer
End Class
```

Comment: wow that looks promising ill try that thanks mate. :)

Comment: i used your code example and modified it a little for my project. it works like a charm. thank you!